# Magento 2 - Override style which is in vendor/foo/bar/view/base/web/css/source/module/components/_foo.less from own theme?

Tags: magento2, css, less, styles

How can I override the file **vendor/foo/bar/view/base/web/css/source/module/components/_foo.less**

I put it in my theme at **app/design/frontend/company/fresh/Foo_Bar/templates/web/css/source/module/components/_foo.less** but my changes are not getting applied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's change your file path:
app/design/frontend/company/fresh/Foo_Bar/`templates/`web/css/source/module/components/_foo.less

to
app/design/frontend/company/fresh/Foo_Bar/web/css/source/module/components/_foo.less

Comment: Oh, that was awkward. Sometimes you dont see the forest because of too many trees... sry

Comment: I totally agree with you. Cheers.